Edubuntu 24.04 not recognizing Apple Broadcom wifi (old mac)
I have an old macbook 5.2 2009.
I previously had ubuntu 22.04, worked great with wifi and everything.
Now I installed Edubuntu 24.04, I selected the checkbox for additional third-party packages for wifi, but the desktop comes up with no wifi available.
The device is broadcom BCM4322 14e4:432b (rev 01)
Did Ubuntu stop supporting this in v24? Should I revert to v22?
Update 08/05/24:
I've done some more digging and I think Canonical didn't update bcmwl-kernel-source for the new kernel.

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Conventional wisdom suggests upgrading after the first point of release, which in this case will be this summer (around August) is the best plan. Don't be too hasty - you might live to regret it if you read some of the questions raised here over the past few days.

You need the driver:
sudo apt firmware-b43legacy-installer


I believe this is the wrong driver. According to AskUbuntu, the correct driver should be bcmwl-kernel-source. https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

I completed the install without internet connectivity and choosing to install 3rd party installations, after the installation was completed, wifi was accessible.

Can you share your network interface details? It varies between different Macs. You can run 'lspci -nn -d 14e4:'

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Dual Band Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)

Ok so this is a different macbook and different network card. Not sure which driver it's using, but probably a different driver.
